# whiile using __sub__ , the desired result is not produced in a Fraction class

Tags: python-3.x

**Sub** didn't work properly, instead of substraction in the num , it adds the num values. see my code below, other operators are working perfectly. 
any help is welcome with respect. :)

```
def gcd(m,n):
while m%n != 0:
    oldm = m
    oldn = n

    m = oldn
    n = oldm%oldn
return n

class Fraction:
     def __init__(self,top,bottom):
         self.num = top
         self.den = bottom

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)

     def show(self):
         print(self.num,"/",self.den)

     def __add__(self,otherfraction):
         newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den + \
                  self.den*otherfraction.num
         newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
         common = gcd(newnum,newden)
         return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)

     def __mul__(self,otherm):
         newnum = self.num * otherm.num
         newden = self.den * otherm.den
         return Fraction(newnum, newden)

     def __truediv__(self,otherd):
         newnum = self.num * otherd.den
         newden = self.den * otherd.num
         common = gcd(newnum, newden)
         return Fraction(newnum // common, newden // common)

     def __eq__(self, other):
         firstnum = self.num * other.den
         secondnum = other.num * self.den

         return firstnum == secondnum

     def __sub__(self,others):
         firstnum = (self.num * others.den) - (self.den * others.den) 
         secondnum = (self.den * others.den)
         common = gcd(firstnum, secondnum)
         return Fraction(firstnum // common, secondnum // common)

x = Fraction(1,3)
y = Fraction(1,3)
print(x+y)
print(x == y)
print(x * y)
print(x / y)
print(x - y)
```

the results produced by the machine is:
2/3
True
1/9
-2/3.

see the last one , rather than substracting, it adds in the denominator.
the actual result should be 0

Comment: Why don't you normalize products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at a first glance i'd say you got the numerator wrong in your `__sub__`. it should be:

```
 def __sub__(self,others):
     firstnum = (self.num * others.den) - (self.den * others.num)  # <--
     secondnum = (self.den * others.den)
     common = gcd(firstnum, secondnum)
     return Fraction(firstnum // common, secondnum // common)
```

in the line i marked with a comment i replaced `ohters.den` with `others.num`.

(not tested...)

i hope you are doing this as an exercise and you are aware that [`math.gcd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) and [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction) are implemented in python.

also gcd could be written more concise:

```
def gcd(a, b):
   while b:
       a, b = b, a % b
   return a
```

Comment: peace from india :) i am new in coding. so forgive me for this silly mistake. and thanks again you helps me a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to use:

```
 def __sub__(self,others):
     return self + (others * Fraction(-1,1)) # since a-b = a+(-1*b)
```